# How to get the closest ul element to the given css offset using jquery

Tags: jquery

Any suggestion, how to get the closest ul element to the given css offset using jquery.

e.g something like this:-

```
var object = jQuery().closest({left: 331, top: 25});
```

object holds the nearest ul element

Note: The idea is to find the nearest element to a dropped element from html page or view page using jquery.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the method. It expects a selector, not a set of CSS properties as a parameter. [,closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this, the question makes sense and there is a solution. Don't downvote just because the grammar is not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No jQuery needed, use [document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(331, 25);
```

There's also a [jQuery.nearest](http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-nearest/) plugin that probably does exactly what you want.